# Make users unable to save images

Tags: html, css

I want to protect image from downloading from ordinary users, like this

```
<div style="background-image: url(img.jpg); background-size: cover; background-repeat: none; ">
<img src="wtrmrk.jpg" style=" opacity: 0; " />
</div>
```

As long as the `img.jpg` has an unknown size how can I control the DIV width to match `img.jpg` width?

Comment: What do you mean, that 'the DIV-width to be fixed at "img.jpg" ' ? ... Is it, that you want the div to have the same width as the image inside of it? In that case, then I would put 'display: block; height: auto; width: auto; overflow: hidden;' on the div - and then it might work. You might have to put 'float: left' on it as well. Not all of that CSS is necessary, but in case of browser-differences, I would write it like that.

Comment: Watermarks are your best bet, since anyone can can just printscreen and crop the image. Even watermarks can be removed with a little photoshop skill. Only display low res versions of the pictures if you really want to protect them, sell the hi res.

Comment: i am designing a website for photography studio and they want to protect their images, I already told them that the best way of protecting them is to not upload them but they insist to at least protect them from ordinary viewers, the original image will have a watermark and a transparent watermark. your solution doesn't work div still stretch to screen size width :( @Zeth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For unknown dimensions, I'd go with overlays. You could create an absolutely positioned element and expand its dimensions by `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties in order to cover the image as follows:

```css
.wrapper { position: relative; display: inline-block; }

.wrapper img { vertical-align: bottom; }

.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200"/>
</div>
```